# No compiler warning by inconsistent function parameter use

Tags: c, function, pointers, gcc, parameters

During a C code review of the software that did not want to run on the target HW, the  following inconsistency has been discovered in a function use:

The SW component 1 implements the function:

```
void foo(uint8 par_var[2])
```

The function `foo()` also writes the two element of the `par_var` array.

The SW component 2 gets an external declaration of the foo() as following

```
extern void foo(uint8 *par_var)
```

and uses it as following :

```
uint8 par_var;

foo(&par_var); //-> sending a pointer to a scalar
               //   instead to an array of 2 elements.
```

Obviously, it may lead and leads actually to the program failure.

The question is, if it could be possible for compiler/linker to intercept the inconsistency by issuing a warning, for example.

I have scanned and tried some of the gcc (CygWin) compiler options along with the standard ones (-Wall, -pedantic  ) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Warning-Options.html

but could not find one that could issue a corresponding warning .

Comment: Compilers tend not to do such deep analysis. There are other tools that can do static analysis of code and that might be able to figure it out. It's *very* hard though, especially if the function is defined in a different translation unit.

Comment: Even when defined as `void foo(uint8 par_var[2])` the compiler ignores the `2` which places no restriction on the indexing.

Comment: To increase odds of getting any kind of warning, declaration should include the array size: `extern void foo(uint8 par_var[2])`. I would expect that this kind of warning would be generated by compiler, not linker.

Comment: Boundaries check are nod checked by compiler. You have the same for a string char[2] and char*. Note: the declaration defines the API (for programmers), so that API should be make clear that you want two pairs. If you need to have better checks, use struct

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: The question requests type checking, not boundary checking. Ideally for the OP, the compiler would recognize that `&par_var` is a pointer to a single `char` while the parameter to `foo` is an array of 2 `char` (that was adjusted to a pointer). Of course, we know C defeats this by its automatic adjustment, but the fact remains that no boundary check (no check of what actual indices are used) is requested here, just a type check.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : RIght

Answer (score 5):

There is a C feature that could aid a compiler in diagnosing this, but I am not aware of a compiler that takes advantage of it and warns. If `foo` were declared as `void foo(uint8 par_var[static 2]);`, then a caller is required to pass a pointer to at least two elements, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 7:

> If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

So, a compiler seeing `uint8 par_var; foo(&par_var);` could recognize the failure to pass two elements and provide a warning. (While I am not aware of compilers that check the declared size, some compilers will warn when a null pointer is passed for such a parameter.)

As is well known, in the declaration `void foo(uint8 par_var[2])`, `par_var` is automatically adjusted to `uint8 *par_var`. As an alternative, instead of passing a pointer to `uint8`, you could pass a pointer to an array of `uint8` by declaring `foo` as `void foo(uint8 (*par_var)[2]);`.

Then you would have to pass it an array, such as:

```
uint8 A[2];
foo(&A);
```

If it were called with a pointer to `uint8`, the compiler should issue a warning. Unfortunately, this also constraints the routine; you **must** pass it a pointer to an array of two `uint8` and cannot pass it a pointer to a larger array or a pointer to a `uint8` in a larger array. So it has limited use. Nonetheless, it could serve in certain situations.

Comment: Thank all for comments, it would be not bad if the using of the keyword _static_ in array size in parameter declaration would pop up a corresponding error, but at least _gcc_ totally ignores it. Moreover, _MISRA-C:2012, Rule 17.6_ explicitly forbids such declarations. I had in fact the warning issued by declaring the parameter of `foo()` in SWC1 as a pointer to an array of two elements, as was proposed by @EricPostpischil.

Comment: At present SWC2, that uses the function `foo()`, is a generated code. Whereas SWC1 is a hand-written code. Moreover, the code generation tool does not/cannot generate a pointer to an array. So the way we are going is to reinforce the code review of the generated code and its corresponding API.

Comment: The question is whether `typedef int a2T[2]; uint8 a4[4]; void foo(uint8 (*par_var)[2]); void f(){foo((a2T*)(a4+1));}` is legal (I'd say yes). In that case the usability/size restrictions of such a pointer-to-array declaration wouldn't be as bad.